# How to save a ModelForm that has conditionally-declared fields in __init__ but not in the Meta class?

Tags: python, django

I have a ModelForm that I can't save properly:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):

    foobar = forms.IntegerField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        baz = kwargs.pop('baz', None)
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if baz:
            self.fields['baz'] = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = FooBar
        fields = ('foobar',)
```

Running the debugger when I try to save shows that `baz` is present in `fields` and `cleaned_data`, but unless I declare it in the `Meta.fields` then it doesn't save this field.

How do I proceed in this situation? I don't know if I need `baz` in my fields until the form in initialized - how can I express this condition in the Meta class?

Edit: Not at all a duplicate of "how do I make a field optional"-style questions. Making a field optional means it's declared statically, implying you know what fields your form is supposed to have in advance, and will be rendered with the other form fields if you don't include business logic in the template (which I'm trying to avoid, as it doesn't belong there in my case). This questions concerns dynamicaly including a field in a ModelForm and still being able to call the save() method successfully.

Comment: Alessio, can you remove your duplicate flag or provide a generalised solution that takes account of the information included my edit?

Comment: Sorry, I misenterpreted your question, the flag is removed ;)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can try to save the model manually, that means that instead of doing:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

You can do something like:

```
if form.is_valid():
    if condition:
        YourModel.objects.create(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've realised that the simplest way to do this would be to avoid touching the form's `save` method altogether, and instead add the field to the Meta class as required:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    baz = kwargs.pop('baz', None)
    super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if baz:
        self.fields['baz'] = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
        self._meta.fields += ('baz',)
```